# Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; : At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

---

public interface EmployeeInterface extends CrudRepository{
}

---

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeInterface empInterface;

    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return (List<Employee>)empInterface.findAll();
    }
}
```

---

Employee entity with getters and setters

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5406213393320888178L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="fname")
    private String fname;
    @Column(name="lname")
    private String lname;
```

When i execute the jar created

java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=container -jar demo.jar

I see this error

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Comment: public interface EmployeeInterface extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long>{
    
}

Comment: spring:
  profiles: container
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}
    username: ${DATABASE_USER}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    initialize: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: You are mixing Spring Boot 1 and Spring Boot 2. Please use [one of the dependency management options](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-parent-pom) and stop overriding versions manually.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll : I am not clear with what you mean. Can you pls tell me where i am mixing both?

Comment: Look at the answers though I wouldn't recommend harcoding version for modules (please refer to the link in my first comment for more details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

you use spring boot version 1.5.6 but give jpa dependency of spring boot 2.0.3

change your mysql connector version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, changing the version solved the existing issue.

Comment: But now i have a new problem. My application is not able to connect to the database. I see the below error

Comment: Glad. you can accept solution for further reference :)

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
 ... 96 common frames omitted

Comment: add properties in your question

Comment: ## YAML Template.
---
spring:
  profiles: container
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}
    username: ${DATABASE_USER}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    initialize: true
    tomcat:
      max-active: 1
    
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: change your mysql connector version. i updated answer

Comment: Changing the version of mysql-connector does not solve the problem. it still says connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Look at your POM entries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The versions you use for spring boot are 1.5 and 2.0. Spring boot starter uses 1.5.6 in your case and your starter jpa uses 2.0 which is way too different in terms of compatibility. Always use the same version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This above should solve that JPA bean creation problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error, i was trying to connect to a schema which did not exist. Had to remove schema name from application.properties file. Then it worked.